# How do I get started in Computer Vision?

Tags: computer-vision

I want to know how to write and run the correct code. I understand that I need to download OpenCV (which I have), but when I try to compile sample code - for example, Blob Detection - it doesn't compile. I am just very confused on the process of what you need to do to get something to show up on the screen. 
I know my question is really vague, but I have such a bad understanding of Computer Vision that I don't really know how to describe my problem. Hopefully discussing more will be able to help me.

Please help me! I have been searching the Internet for 2 hours now and I am just lost in a sea of information...

Answer (score 1):

First try going through tutorials on the official OpenCV website: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html
There they don't talk only about OpenCV functions but also explain some basic concepts of image processing along the way.

I also recommend this course, it can help you grasp some basic concepts related to geometry: https://class.coursera.org/vision

Finally, this is a great book but it is a bit depricated http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf so use it with caution of that if you will.

Regards,
Damjan

Comment: I recommend "OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming 
Cookbook" by http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/ - it is a really good book of recipes from the very beginning. And it uses C++ interface to OpenCV, not deprecated C style used in O`Reilly book.